# CLIPS Rules trigger more than once

Tags: system, rules, clip, clips

Hi im trying to make an expert system in Clips, but when a Plant should trigger only one time the rule it trigger as much times as characteristics coincide within the ones specified in the rule, is there a way to make this rule trigger only once per plant in the facts?

I tried with the test() (by putting all the conditions or() included in the test) statement but it didn't work it would give me troubles with the plant template

Example of the rule

```
(defrule ruleexp
   (or
   (Plant (grownt normal))
   (Plant (leaf purple))
   (Plant (roots burned))
   (Plant (fruit dry)))
   =>
   (printout t "this should print only once" crlf))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **exists** conditional element to create just one activation:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate Plant
   (slot growth)
   (slot leaf)
   (slot roots)
   (slot fruit))
CLIPS>    
(defrule ruleexp
   (exists 
      (or (Plant (growth normal))
          (Plant (leaf purple))
          (Plant (roots burned))
          (Plant (fruit dry))))
   =>
   (printout t "this should print only once" crlf))
CLIPS>    
(assert (Plant (growth normal) 
               (leaf blue)
               (roots burned) 
               (fruit wet)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
this should print only once
CLIPS>
```